# Advanced web debugging (firebug, etc), specifically with site scripts

Tags: jquery, html, firebug, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am trying to figure out how to use an **inspector tool** *(Chrome's built in inspector or firebug, etc)* in a specific way. For demonstrative purposes here is an example of what I want to accomplish:

I have a site that uses some sort of **javascript/jQuery** calls/scripts to handle certain element changes. These changes are in the form of switching images (slideshow, etc) by altering the CSS associated with them. Or they could be something like expanding/contracting **HTML divs** according to screen size...

Is there anyway to pinpoint the code that is controlling these changes? Im guessing - but not sure - that this is some sort of break-point setting (?)..

I just want to be able to see what is controlling the slideshow/button/etc. I hope this makes enough sense for an accurate response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements - > Event Listeners, to check what listeners exist now. 
Sources -> EventListenerBreakpoins, to add your own.